# How to configure Ejabberd server with MSSQL

Tags: ejabberd

I'm trying to connect Ejabberd server with MSSQL in linux. As of now I have installed Ejabberd 18.01 and MSSQL in ubuntu. Also Dumped all Mnesia tables into MSSQL. From the documentation page I'm getting to know that we need to configure freetds and unixODBC. I tried multiple configuration as suggested by official website but still not able to create the connection. Can someone please help to get it resolved?